# images not displaying using array with input and ngFor - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

I'm trying to display an array of images via their source link using an ngFor but I am receiving errors and it's not working!

The image **HTML** code which is within my card component:

```
<div class="Session-Participants">
    <div  *ngFor="let image of {{ participantImages }}" >
        <img src='{{image}}'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the **JS** file:

```
@Input() participantImages? = [];
```

The data is coming from my other component and the html and JS are as below:

```
<div *ngFor="let sessions of getSortedSessionList()">
    <div *ngFor="let session of sessions">
        <tl-session-card
          [title]="session.name"
          [path]="sessionPath(session.id, session.name)"
          [participantImages]="getParticipantDetails(session)" // HERE
         >     
        </tl-session-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

the JS:

```
participantImage = [];

getParticipantDetails(session) {
    this.participantImage = session.roles[0].account.thumbnailURL;
    return this.participantImage;
}
```

I'm expecting for the 'this.participantImage' to be returned and then sent to the card component and then broken down to be displayed separately.

I'm sure I am missing something?

Thanks if you can help at all?

Comment: a stackblitz with a minimal working code would make it much easier to help.

Comment: Okay, sorry where it was complicated I wasn't sure whether I should try to create one before posting, I will do it.

Comment: Maybe not really the answer , but some things I noticed:

1) Why not put the ngfor on the <tl-session-card> and not on the wrapping div?
2) Why not just pass the session from the ngfor into the <tl-session-card> instead of tiny little bits of property bindings? This way you have more control in the <tl-session-card> over the incomming data
3) getParticipantDetails() returns a string but you have a @Input() expecting an array?
4) The <tl-session-card> component should implement the img tag with the thumbnail url.

Comment: why you put  {{ participantImages }}"  instead of <div class="Session-Participants">
  <div  *ngFor="let image of  participantImages " >
      <img src='{{image}}'/>
    </div>

Comment: I thought thats what you needed for the input to work

Comment: I removed it and got this error: annot find a differ supporting object 'imagelink12312312' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: The issue is you're returning a string, not an array, even though you declared an array. In your method getParticipantDetails you only set the output to the thumbnail, while it expects an array in ngFor, so you get error.

Comment: @zuckerburg how can I resolve it - so it returns an array?

Comment: @Sparlarva try: `this.participantImage.push(session.roles[0].account.thumbnailURL);`

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndmlcr

Comment: is that what you wanted?

Comment: Hi Prashant, that does allow for an image to be displayed, well the array itself is appearing empty I think I am not manipulating the data set correctly, I will post it

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the stackblitz link, you have a proper array and that not reflect perfectly the code you just provide above.

You need to ensure `participantImage` stay an array otherwise, the `ngFor` will not work as expected and you will see some errors in your console.

as @prashant-pimpale says, you need to append to the list of `participantImage` the result.

In the ts file It would be better to use

```
participantImage = [];

getParticipantDetails(session) {
    // ensures this.participanImage keeps its array type and will process all
    // other roles
    this.participantImage = session.roles.map(account => account.thumbnailURL);
    return this.participantImage;
}
```

Hope it helps

PS: would be better to set the attribute name of `participantImage` to `participantImages` since it represent a list of images ;)